# how to use var properly

Tags: javascript, prompt, var

I just started learning Javascript on codecademy and don't know what is the problem with this code.

```
var feedback = prompt("Rate this game out of 10");
if(feedback > 8) {
    console.log("This is just the beginning of my game empire. Stay tuned for more!");
}
else {
    console.log("I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you wait!")
};
```

It says there's something wrong with variable. It might be a too easy question, but I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: "It says there's something wrong with variable." And what does "it" say exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue like Klaasman pointed out, is that you had a newline break.

```
console.log("This is a very long string
that went more than one line long");
```

If you want strings to go  more than one line you have to use \ to tell JavaScript that "The string is continued on the next line"

```
console.log("This is a very long string \
that went more than one line long");
```

This way you could write the same string like this:

```
console.log("This \
is \
a \
very \
long \ 
string");
```

You also forgot a semicolon on your last console.log statement.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript it's not allowed to have a hard break in a string.

this line:

```
console.log("I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you          
wait!")};
```

should be:

```
console.log("I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you wait!")};
```

Comment: \ can be added to a string to deal with line breaks.

Comment: very true, but I don't think it's a good idea to learn someone, who is starting with javascript, it's possible to escape such characters.

Comment: Many beginners don't understand what a "hard break" is. Please explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me.
The only thing is a newline in the second console.log statement , but I don't know if this was just a copy&paste error you made while posting.